# Ajax Request returning the whole page not a specifc value

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, ajax, controller, json

I am trying to make an AJAX Request to my function in my controller and it works, however, it returns me the whole page which i don't want. I have tried encoding it with `json` but no success i also have tried different formats in the url such as `format=raw`, `format=ajax` and `format=json` none of them worked and both 
`format=raw` and `format=json` gave me a 404 error.

So, what i am trying to do, is a request to a function in my controller that should return me "ok" but, instead of returning "ok", it gives me the whole HTML. I surely am missing something, i just don't know what it is. I have tried changing the URL parameter, `dataType` but still same result. Plus, i have seen some examples wihout the controller name in the url parameter;

**example:**

`url: index.php?option=com_gallery&task=submit` but it didn't work out for me nor did this:
`url: index.php?option=com_gallery&controller=send&task=submit`; this is the only thing that has worked out for me: `index.php?option=com_gallery&task=send.submit`.

Any clarifications about these url parameters when it comes to AJAX requests to the controller and its methods?

My ajax request:

```
$.ajax(
    {   url: 'index.php?option=com_gallery&task=send.submit',    
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',       
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },      
        error:function(){
            alert("error");
        },

        });
}
```

My controller `send.php`

```
defined('_EXEC') or die ('Restricted access');


class GalleryControllerSend extends JControllerForm
{


      public function submit($key=null, $urlVar=null)
      {
         echo "ok";        
      }

}
```

What should i do to display just the "ok" in the function `submit()` ?

The only thing that has worked out was adding `format=html` to the url parameter and adding `exit();` below the `echo "ok"` but i believe that's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is include `&format=json` in your URL. This tells Joomla that you want a JSON response rather than HTML, and it won't run (subsequently) your template to produce all your page HTML.

The usual approach is to call

```
parent::display()
```

in your controller code (ie in submit()). This will cause Joomla to look for a `display()` function in a `view.json.php` file with the same class name as in your `view.html.php` file. There you should be able to do:

```
echo new JResponseJson('ok');
```

The JResponseJson class will look after stopping the application at that point as there's no need to continue on.

For an example view.json.php file see https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_AJAX#site.2Fviews.2Fhelloworld.2Fview.json.php

I suggest you omit the datatype - jQuery will be able to figure it out.

Comment: Yes you talked about `JResponseJson` but i tried to start off the the basics haha, could not get it working tho. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your task must be in the component main controller, I mean the controller.php, not in the send.php controller and then you can use "url: index.php?option=com_gallery&task=submit&view=myview&format=json".

In your controller function submit(){parent::display();} will be enough. You also need a "myview" view.json.php

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Maikol.  Thank you for contributing.  Please take our [tour].